# Double tap or single tap on mouse pad synaptics 19.0.12.95 on windows 10 not working

Tags: windows, mouse, touchpad, synaptics-touchpad

Double tap or single tap on mouse pad synaptics 19.0.12.95 on windows 10 not working. Will I have to wait for updated driver or is there a way to change settings? I previously had windows 7.

Comment: You likely have to wait for updated drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works on my HP Pavilion laptop.

As we know, Windows 10 automatically updates, in this case installing the Synaptics driver version 19.0.12.95, which keeps resetting certain settings.

Download and install the Synaptics driver version ["19.0.12.95 Rev: A Pass: 14"](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp72001-72500/sp72120.exe) released by HP (07/08/2015).

After installing the driver (no need to uninstall the previous drivers), reboot, set your settings, and they will no longer be reset in future reboots. However, Windows will still want to install the problematic version of the driver. That can be stopped with a Group Policy tweak:

Run `gpedit.msc`, Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, System, Device Installation, Device Installation Restrictions, and double-click "Prevent installation of devices that match any of these device IDs" or "Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings". Select Enabled and perform the necessary changes as detailed in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530324.aspx).

Once a fixed driver is distributed through Windows Update, you can remove the restriction by setting that policy to Not Configured.